# add the day information to timestep in a dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to read the csv file into a dataframe,the csv fileThe csv file looks like this.

[image: 1]

The cell value only contains the hour information and miss the day information. I would like to read this csv file into a dataframe and transform the timing information into the format like `2021-05-07 04:04.00` i.e., I would like to add the day information. How to achieve that?

I used the following code, but it seems that pyspark just add the day information as `1970-01-01`, kind of system setting.

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy","LEGACY")
df_1 = spark.read.csv('test1.csv', header = True)
df_1 = df_1.withColumn('Timestamp', to_timestamp(col('Timing'), 'HH:mm'))
df_1.show(truncate=False)
```

And I got the following result.

```
+-------+-------------------+
| Timing|          Timestamp|
+-------+-------------------+
|04:04.0|1970-01-01 04:04:00|
|19:04.0|1970-01-01 19:04:00|
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concat a date string before calling `to_timestamp`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df_1.withColumn(
    'Timestamp', 
    F.to_timestamp(
        F.concat_ws(' ', F.lit('2021-05-07'), 'Timing'), 
        'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm.s'
    )
)

df2.show()
+-------+-------------------+
| Timing|          Timestamp|
+-------+-------------------+
|04:04.0|2021-05-07 04:04:00|
|19:04.0|2021-05-07 19:04:00|
+-------+-------------------+
```